# php validation class is not validating correctly

Tags: php, validation

am using a PHP validation class which i got from the internet, but am having some trouble,

am expecting to get this msg when nothing is entered to the form fields(**fieldname is not set**), but  it display nothing if the type is **string**. and it display (**fieldname is an invalid number**) if the type is **numeric**

when somethind is entered  and the **type is string** or **type is numeric**   it prints (**fieldname is too long**)
even if i didn't specify the **min and max**,

i also get this notice from my validation class

```
   Notice: Undefined index: min in C:\xampp\htdocs\RIS\class\validation..
```

Notice: Undefined index: min in C:\xampp\htdocs\RIS\class\validation

```
this is my **validation file**

    <?php

    class validation{

    /*
    * @errors array
    */
    public $errors = array();

    /*
    * @the validation rules array


     */
        private $validation_rules = array();

        /*
         * @the sanitized values array
         */
        public $sanitized = array();

        /*
         * @the source 
         */
        private $source = array();


        /**
         *
         * @t

he constructor, duh!
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @add the source
     *
     * @paccess public
     *
     * @param array $source
     *
     */
    public function addSource($source, $trim=false)
    {
        $this->source = $source;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @run the validation rules
     *
     * @access public
     *
     */
    public function run()
    {
        /*** set the vars ***/
        foreach( new ArrayIterator($this->validation_rules) as $var=>$opt)
        {
            if($opt['required'] == true)
            {
                $this->is_set($var);
            }

            /*** Trim whitespace from beginning and end of variable ***/
            if( array_key_exists('trim', $opt) && $opt['trim'] == true )
            {
                $this->source[$var] = trim( $this->source[$var] );
            }

            switch($opt['type'])
            {
                case 'email':
                    $this->validateEmail($var, $opt['required']);
                    if(!array_key_exists($var, $this->errors))
                    {
                        $this->sanitizeEmail($var);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'url':
                    $this->validateUrl($var);
                    if(!array_key_exists($var, $this->errors))
                    {
                        $this->sanitizeUrl($var);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'numeric':
                    $this->validateNumeric($var, $opt['min'], $opt['max'], $opt['required']);
                    if(!array_key_exists($var, $this->errors))
                    {
                        $this->sanitizeNumeric($var);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'string':
                    $this->validateString($var, $opt['min'], $opt['max'], $opt['required']);
                    if(!array_key_exists($var, $this->errors))
                    {
                        $this->sanitizeString($var);
                    }
                break;

                case 'float':
                    $this->validateFloat($var, $opt['required']);
                    if(!array_key_exists($var, $this->errors))
                    {
                        $this->sanitizeFloat($var);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'ipv4':
                    $this->validateIpv4($var, $opt['required']);
                    if(!array_key_exists($var, $this->errors))
                    {
                        $this->sanitizeIpv4($var);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'ipv6':
                    $this->validateIpv6($var, $opt['required']);
                    if(!array_key_exists($var, $this->errors))
                    {
                        $this->sanitizeIpv6($var);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'bool':
                    $this->validateBool($var, $opt['required']);
                    if(!array_key_exists($var, $this->errors))
                    {
                        $this->sanitized[$var] = (bool) $this->source[$var];
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     *
     * @add a rule to the validation rules array
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param string $varname The variable name
     *
     * @param string $type The type of variable
     *
     * @param bool $required If the field is required
     *
     * @param int $min The minimum length or range
     *
     * @param int $max the maximum length or range
     *
     */
    public function addRule($varname, $type, $required=false, $min=0, $max=0, $trim=false)
    {
        $this->validation_rules[$varname] = array('type'=>$type, 'required'=>$required, 'min'=>$min, 'max'=>$max, 'trim'=>$trim);
        /*** allow chaining ***/
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @add multiple rules to teh validation rules array
     *
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $rules_array The array of rules to add
     *
     */
    public function AddRules(array $rules_array)
    {
        $this->validation_rules = array_merge($this->validation_rules, $rules_array);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Check if POST variable is set
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var The POST variable to check
     *
     */
    private function is_set($var)
    {
        if(!isset($this->source[$var]))
        {
            $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is not set';
        }
    }



    /**
     *
     * @validate an ipv4 IP address
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var The variable name
     *
     * @param bool $required
     *
     */
    private function validateIpv4($var, $required=false)
    {
        if($required==false && strlen($this->source[$var]) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(filter_var($this->source[$var], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4) === FALSE)
        {
            $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is not a valid IPv4';
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @validate an ipv6 IP address
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var The variable name
     *
     * @param bool $required
     *
     */
    public function validateIpv6($var, $required=false)
    {
        if($required==false && strlen($this->source[$var]) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(filter_var($this->source[$var], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) === FALSE)
        {
            $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is not a valid IPv6';
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @validate a floating point number
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param $var The variable name
     *
     * @param bool $required
     */
    private function validateFloat($var, $required=false)
    {
        if($required==false && strlen($this->source[$var]) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(filter_var($this->source[$var], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) === false)
        {
            $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is an invalid float';
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @validate a string
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var The variable name
     *
     * @param int $min the minimum string length
     *
     * @param int $max The maximum string length
     *
     * @param bool $required
     *
     */
    private function validateString($var, $min=0, $max=0, $required=false)
    {
        if($required==false && strlen($this->source[$var]) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(isset($this->source[$var]))
        {
            if(strlen($this->source[$var]) < $min)
            {
                $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is too short';
            }
            elseif(strlen($this->source[$var]) > $max)
            {
                $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is too long';
            }
            elseif(!is_string($this->source[$var]))
            {
                $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is invalid';
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @validate an number
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var the variable name
     *
     * @param int $min The minimum number range
     *
     * @param int $max The maximum number range
     *
     * @param bool $required
     *
     */
    private function validateNumeric($var, $min=0, $max=0, $required=false)
    {
        if($required==false && strlen($this->source[$var]) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(filter_var($this->source[$var], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>$min, "max_range"=>$max)))===FALSE)
        {
            $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is an invalid number';
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @validate a url
     *
     * @access private
     *
      * @param string $var The variable name
     *
     * @param bool $required
     *
     */
    private function validateUrl($var, $required=false)
    {
        if($required==false && strlen($this->source[$var]) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(filter_var($this->source[$var], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE)
        {
            $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is not a valid URL';
        }
    }


    /**
     *
     * @validate an email address
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var The variable name 
     *
     * @param bool $required
     *
     */
    private function validateEmail($var, $required=false)
    {
        if($required==false && strlen($this->source[$var]) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if(filter_var($this->source[$var], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE)
        {
            $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is not a valid email address';
        }
    }


    /**
     * @validate a boolean 
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var the variable name
     *
     * @param bool $required
     *
     */
    private function validateBool($var, $required=false)
    {
        if($required==false && strlen($this->source[$var]) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        filter_var($this->source[$var], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        {
            $this->errors[$var] = $var . ' is Invalid';
        }
    }

    ########## SANITIZING METHODS ############


    /**
     *
     * @santize and email
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var The variable name
     *
     * @return string
     *
     */
    public function sanitizeEmail($var)
    {
        $email = preg_replace( '((?:\n|\r|\t|%0A|%0D|%08|%09)+)i' , '', $this->source[$var] );
        $this->sanitized[$var] = (string) filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    }


    /**
     *
     * @sanitize a url
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var The variable name
     *
     */
    private function sanitizeUrl($var)
    {
        $this->sanitized[$var] = (string) filter_var($this->source[$var],  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @sanitize a numeric value
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var The variable name
     *
     */
    private function sanitizeNumeric($var)
    {
        $this->sanitized[$var] = (int) filter_var($this->source[$var], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @sanitize a string
     *
     * @access private
     *
     * @param string $var The variable name
     *
     */
    private function sanitizeString($var)
    {
        $this->sanitized[$var] = (string) filter_var($this->source[$var], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }

    } /*** end of class ***/

    ?>
```

**my add_product.php file**

```
    <?php 
    require_once'../core/config.php';
    require_once'../class/database.class.php';
    require_once'../class/validation.class.php';


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name =$_POST['name'];
    $bprice =$_POST['bprice'];
    $sprice =$_POST['sprice'];
    $quantity =$_POST['quantity'];
    $exdate =$_POST['exdate'];
    $date_added =$_POST['date_added'];
    $type_id =$_POST['type_id'];


    $POST = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'bprice' => $bprice,
    'sprice' => $sprice,
    'quantity'=>$quantity,
    'exdate' => $exdate,
    'date_added' => $date_added,
    'type_id' => $type_id);


      /*** an array of rules ***/
       $rules_array = array(
        'name'=>array('type'=>'string',  'required'=>true,'trim'=>true),
        'bprice'=>array('type'=>'numeric', 'required'=>true,'trim'=>true),
        'sprice'=>array('type'=>'numeric', 'required'=>true, 'trim'=>true),
        'quantity'=>array('type'=>'numeric', 'required'=>true, 'trim'=>true),
        'exdate'=>array('type'=>'string', 'required'=>true,  'trim'=>true),
        'date_added'=>array('type'=>'string', 'required'=>true, 'trim'=>true),
        'type_id'=>array('type'=>'numeric', 'required'=>true, 'min'=>1,'trim'=>true)
        );

      /*** a new validation instance ***/
      $val = new validation;

      /*** use POST as the source ***/
      $val->addSource($POST);


      /*** add an array of rules ***/
     $val->addRules($rules_array);

    /*** run the validation rules ***/
    $val->run();

    /*** if there are errors show them ***/
    if(sizeof($val->errors) > 0)
    {
       foreach ($val->errors as $key => $value) {
          echo $value. ' '.'<br>';
       }
    }

    else{




    $database = new Database();

    $database->query("INSERT INTO  
            products(id,name,bprice,sprice,quantity,exdate,date_added,type_id)

         VALUES(:id,:name,:bprice,:sprice,:quantity,:exdate,:date_added,:type_id)");

    $database->bind('id','');
    $database->bind('name',$name);
    $database->bind('bprice',$bprice);
    $database->bind('sprice',$sprice);
    $database->bind('quantity',$quantity);
    $database->bind('exdate',$exdate);
    $database->bind('date_added',$date_added);
    $database->bind('type_id',$type_id);

    $database->execute();

    /*** show the array of validated and sanitized variables ***/
     print_r($val->sanitized);



          }

      }


    ?>

    <div id="contacts">
    <div class="row"><!-- Alignment -->
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
      <!-- Form itself -->
    <form class="well"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">

      <div class="controls">&nbsp;</div>
       <!-- Full Name -->
     <label class="control-label">Name</label>

       <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text"
       placeholder="Name of product"    name="name" />

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">&nbsp;</div>


    <label class="control-label">Buying Price</label>

    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="form-control" id="bprice" type="text"  
       placeholder="Enter Buying   Price" name="bprice" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">&nbsp;</div>

    <label class="control-label">Seling Price</label>

    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="form-control" id="sprice" type="text"
     placeholder="Enter Selling Price" name="sprice" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">&nbsp;</div>

    <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>

   <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="form-control" id="quantity" type="text"
     placeholder="Enter Quantity" name="quantity" /></div>
    </div>


    <div class="controls">&nbsp;</div>

    <label class="control-label">Expire Date</label>

    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="form-control" id="exdate" type="text"
     placeholder="Enter Expire Date" name="exdate" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">&nbsp;</div>

    <label class="control-label">Date Added</label>

    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="form-control" id="date_added" type="text"
     placeholder="Enter Date added" name="date_added" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">&nbsp;</div>

    <label class="control-label">Type ID</label>

    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="form-control" id="type_id" type="text" 
    placeholder="Enter Type ID" name="type_id" /></div>
    </div>


    <div class="controls">&nbsp;</div>

     <button class="btn btn-primary pull-left" type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
    <div class="controls">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="controls">&nbsp;</div>
    </form></div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

any help plz?

Comment: Where did you get the Validation class? That is probably the place that can help you best ;)

Comment: Please put only specific lines and code, not whole page

Comment: i got from [link](http://phpro.org/classes/Validation-Class.html) @kingkero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly simple. Whilst you're checking for some keys (`array_key_exists('trim', $opt)`) in the `$opt` array, you're just assuming the keys `min` and `max` to be set, always.
For example here:

```
     case 'numeric':
                $this->validateNumeric($var, $opt['min'], $opt['max'], $opt['required']);
```

Yet you're passing the opt array without these both keys, save for 1 exception, where you specify a `min` value, but still no max.

```
array(
    'name'=>array('type'=>'string',  'required'=>true,'trim'=>true),
    'bprice'=>array('type'=>'numeric', 'required'=>true,'trim'=>true),
    'sprice'=>array('type'=>'numeric', 'required'=>true, 'trim'=>true),
    'quantity'=>array('type'=>'numeric', 'required'=>true, 'trim'=>true),
    'exdate'=>array('type'=>'string', 'required'=>true,  'trim'=>true),
    'date_added'=>array('type'=>'string', 'required'=>true, 'trim'=>true),
    'type_id'=>array('type'=>'numeric', 'required'=>true, 'min'=>1,'trim'=>true)
    );
```

You're not getting a fatal error, because PHP defaults the value of undefined indexes to `null`, but it *will* produce a notice, as you've noticed.
The answer is to either introduce a check in your method:

```
$opt['min'] = isset($opt['min']) ? $opt['min'] : 0;//default to 0
$opt['max'] = isset($opt['max']) ? $opt['max'] : 0;//some def value
```

or to pass the keys, always.
Another way to deal with this would be to check if these values are set, and if not, *not* to perform min-max validation.

Lastly, some might suggest suppressing the notice, or lowering the error reporting level. While debugging code, I just want to say, this is a terrible idea. Notices are tools to help you improve on your code. It means there's something wrong.
If there's something not *quite* right, ***fix it, don't ignore it***

Comment: thenx, bt nw the string if empty is not validated

Answer (score 0):

Function of you validation class in validateString has default min and max (equal 0). I just guessing is that your problem. Maybe you need set min, max in your code. Like this (remember I just guessing

`'date_added'=>array('type'=>'string', 'required'=>true, 'trim'=>true, 'min' => 0, 'max'=>'50'`),